# Can mold in a building cause fatigue?

Tags: mold

Pretty much what the title says, **can mold in a building cause fatigue?**

I've been working with the same company for almost 11 years. The first 2 and a half years I was at another building until they moved my department to another one. My health at that building was never in question, didn't seem like anything effected me at all.

I know ever since coming into this building my allergies started getting worse and my sinuses would bother me really bad as well. Literally I could walk into the building and my eyes would turn bloodshot red because of whatever is in the building.

Lately when I've been coming into work, I feel so tired/fatigued after being in the building for about 10-15 minutes or so, and it doesn't go away. *I know they found mold in the building before when they stripped down the wallpaper.*

Can mold in a building cause fatigue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible that there is mold or other agents in the building that can be either causing or contributing to allergy and fatigue symptoms.

[Here is a writeup](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/Sick-building-syndrome/Pages/Introduction.aspx) on what is called sick building syndrome (SBS) from National Health in the UK. [Here is a writeup](http://drhoffman.com/article/molds-mites-and-pollens-common-causes-of-allergic-fatigue-2/) on various agents that can cause the same symptoms from a doctor's blog. There is a similar malady titled "tight" building syndrome as well. SBS can produce the following symptoms:

- headaches and dizziness
- nausea
- aches and pains
- fatigue
- poor concentration
- shortness of breath or chest tightness
- eye and throat irritation

There are quite a few different writeups on SBS and mold related fatigue, and they all seem to indicate that there can be significant health effects from things such as poorly cleaned and/or designed ventilation systems, agents in the carpet/walls, etc. I would highly encourage you to pursue this and get it cleared up.